# Give every "empty" age band 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like the following:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS `members`,
  CASE
    WHEN age >= 10 AND age <= 20 THEN '10-20'
    WHEN age >=21 AND age <=30 THEN '21-30'
    WHEN age >=31 AND age <=40 THEN '31-40'
    WHEN age >=41 AND age <= 50 THEN '41-50'
    WHEN age >=51 AND age <=60 THEN '51-60'
    WHEN age >=61 AND age <=70 THEN '61-70'
    WHEN age >= 71 THEN '71+'
  END AS ageband
FROM `members`
GROUP BY ageband
```

Retrieves

[image]

How do I populate the empty age bands with 0?

This is what I am looking to achieve from my query above:

```
members     ageband
1           10-20
0           21-30
2           31-40
0           41-50
1           51-60
0           61-70
1           71+
```

There are NO member in range of 41-50, hence I put 0.

Comment: may you can try to reword your question? i can think of many things you want, right now

Comment: Unclear what youre asking ...

Comment: I updated my question, the result table above is what I am looking for, all age bands should always come with, but be "0", if the age range say 21-30 there are no member within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows you wish for are not displayed because there's no data for them. Outer join (left or right) all possibilities and they will be displayed:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(members.whatever_column_best_would_be_primary_key) AS `members`,
  ages.age_range
FROM `members`
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT '10-20' as age_range
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '21-30'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '31-40'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '41-50'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '51-60'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '61-70'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '71+'
)ages ON ages.age_range = CASE
    WHEN members.age >= 10 AND age <= 20 THEN '10-20'
    WHEN members.age >=21 AND age <=30 THEN '21-30'
    WHEN members.age >=31 AND age <=40 THEN '31-40'
    WHEN members.age >=41 AND age <= 50 THEN '41-50'
    WHEN members.age >=51 AND age <=60 THEN '51-60'
    WHEN members.age >=61 AND age <=70 THEN '61-70'
    WHEN members.age >= 71 THEN '71+'
  END
GROUP BY ages.age_range
```

Comment: This almost works. However, it outputs 1 instead of 0, on the one who misses. I tried  COALESCE and ELSE, didn't work.

Comment: @user3121056 Edited my answer. You have to count a column of members table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question right. Did you miss the part with `ELSE` in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)?

```
 SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS `members`,
   CASE
     WHEN age >= 10 AND age <= 20 THEN '10-20'
     WHEN age >=21 AND age <=30 THEN '21-30'
     WHEN age >=31 AND age <=40 THEN '31-40'
     WHEN age >=41 AND age <= 50 THEN '41-50'
     WHEN age >=51 AND age <=60 THEN '51-60'
     WHEN age >=61 AND age <=70 THEN '61-70'
     WHEN age >= 71 THEN '71+'
     ELSE '0'
   END AS ageband
 FROM `members`
 GROUP BY ageband
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use coalsce !

try this

```
SELECT
COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS `members`,
CASE
WHEN age >= 10 AND age <= 20 THEN '10-20'
WHEN age >=21 AND age <=30 THEN '21-30'
WHEN age >=31 AND age <=40 THEN '31-40'
WHEN age >=41 AND age <= 50 THEN '41-50'
WHEN age >=51 AND age <=60 THEN '51-60'
WHEN age >=61 AND age <=70 THEN '61-70'
WHEN age >= 71 THEN '71+'
END AS ageband
FROM `members`
GROUP BY ageband
```

Comment: This will not work as you are querying table `members` so if no member is in a given ageband then COALESCE() is not even called.

Answer (score 0):

You can first build a table containing your age bands. Say `CREATE TABLE ages(ageband text);`:

```
min_age | max_age | ageband
---------------------------
10      | 20      | 10-20
21      | 30      | 21-30
31      | 40      | 31-40
41      | 50      | 41-50
51      | 60      | 51-60
61      | 70      | 61-70
71      | 99      | 71+
```

Then you `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(members.*) AS `members`,
  ageband
FROM
   `members`
   FULL OUTER JOIN `ages` ON
       age BETWEEN min_age AND max_age
GROUP BY ageband;
```

(You can't use `COUNT(*)` but have to be more specific and use `COUNT(members.*)` because there will be rows with an empty ageband and `NULL` values coming from members and you want to count them as 0. COUNT() counts non-NULL items only.)

(Furthermore, the advantage of `FULL OUTER JOIN` over `RIGHT JOIN` is that if you have an age not covered, such as 8, 20.5, 101 or text, it will still be listed with an `ageband = NULL` so you see the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

even @FancyPants has been provided solution, you can also try below query in different way:

```
SELECT IFNULL(cnt,0) AS 'members', ages.age_range AS 'ageband' FROM (
    SELECT '10-20' AS age_range
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '21-30'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '31-40'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '41-50'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '51-60'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '61-70'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '71+') AS ages
    LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt,
CASE WHEN age>=10 AND age<=20 THEN '10-20' 
WHEN age>=21 AND age<=30 THEN '21-30' 
WHEN age>=31 AND age<=40 THEN '31-40' 
WHEN age>=41 AND age<=50 THEN '41-50' 
WHEN age>=51 AND age<=60 THEN '51-60' 
WHEN age>=61 AND age<=70 THEN '61-70' 
WHEN age>=71 THEN '71+' END age_range 
FROM members GROUP BY age_range) a 
ON a.age_range=ages.age_range
```